# Javascript 'cvml' in an email address

Tags: javascript, email, gmail

I received a reply from someone with a Gmail address recently.

In the body of the message, it had my return address as:

```
"My name" <myname@mydomain.com<javascript:_e({}, 'cvml','myname@mydomain.com');>>
```

A search online shows this bit of JavaScript code appearing frequently in email messages but no explanation of what it does.

Is this something having to do with Google+?

What is its purpose?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this stems from Cufon-yui.js, which is used to render custom fonts. Cufon uses `cvml` to return `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml` which is an XML namespace for Vector Markup Language.

Comment: Can I somehow prevent it from appearing in emails sent by me?